# Why do I get the permission denied error when creating a table in BigQuery GCP Console with an "owner" account?

Tags: google-bigquery

```
create table if not exists [dataset].[table] (id int64, name string, created_at timestamp) partition by date(created_at) cluster by id;
```

Error running query
Access Denied: Dataset [project]:[dataset]: Permission bigquery.tables.create denied on dataset [project]:[dataset] (or it may not exist).

Comment: can you check you have Bigquery user role or editor

Answer (score 6):

From the Error it can be seen that when you are creating a table in your bigquery you are getting the **bigquery.tables.create** permission denied error.

**bigquery.tables.create** role is used for creating new tables. You are getting this error because you do not have this [permission](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control) enabled in your IAM roles in your project.

**The bigquery.admin** and **bigquery.dataEditor** roles both contain the **bigquery.tables.create** permission. so either should be sufficient.

Make sure that the user being the owner has the permissions on the project in which the job is being run.

You can check for the same by going to -

1. go to google cloud console
2. navigate to IAM and Services
3. Go to roles and check for this role is enabled or not, if not then enable it.

Check this public documentation for Access controls in BigQuery.

[Access Controls](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/access-control-examples)

Comment: It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, please consider to accept and upvote it. 
 https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: When the codes are service accounts, the hard part is working out who is the user..... I've attached BigQuery.DataEditor permission to every service account that I can find. Still no luck :-(